# Doctrine/MySQL: field missing in ResultSetMapping

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a native query an want to fill a ResultSetMapping object with the results of my query.
Everything works as expected, but the field "distance". The field in the resulting array is always empty. When i run my query directly in MySQL there are results for "distance", so i guess my SQL is ok?

```
class PlaceRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllWithMainImage($lat, $lon)
    {
        try
        {
            $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
            $rsm->addScalarResult('slug', 'slug');
            $rsm->addScalarResult('title', 'title');
            $rsm->addScalarResult('rating', 'rating');
            $rsm->addScalarResult('visited_at', 'visited_at');
            $rsm->addScalarResult('img', 'img');
            $rsm->addScalarResult('distance', 'distance');

            return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createNativeQuery('SELECT p.slug, p.title, p.rating, p.visited_at, pp.file AS img, ROUND(GLength(
                        LineString(
                            p.place_point, 
                            GeomFromText("POINT(:lat :lon)")
                        )
                    ) * 111.12, 1) AS distance
                    FROM place p 
                    LEFT JOIN place_picture AS pp
                    ON p.id = pp.place_id
                    GROUP BY p.id
                    ORDER BY distance
                    LIMIT 20', $rsm)
                ->setParameter('lat', $lat)
                ->setParameter('lon', $lon)
                ->getResult();
        }
        catch(\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Repository function called from Crontroller:

```
class PlaceRestController extends Controller
{
    public function getPlacesAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        $view = FOSView::create();
        $view->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = $em->getRepository('TouringPlaceBundle:Place')->getAllWithMainImage(48.39227479328352, 9.985520839691162); //hard-coded for debugging
        print_r($data);  //… [img] => xzz.jpg, [distance] =>
        if($data)
        {
            $view->setStatusCode(200)->setData($data);
        }
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add the part of your code where you are calling this method? 
Where does the return value go? In an entity?

Evenf if I don't think so, the problem might come from the multiples quotes so :lat and :lon are not changed into the values you want them to be. Have you checked the profiler to be sure they are replaced?

Comment: Just added more code. The return value goes to a Scalar Result in the ResultSetMapping. It will be transformed to JSON by FOSRestBundle (i've attached the code is my main posting).

Comment: Wow, you are right with your last suggestion. The :lat and :lon is not replaced correctly. Weird thing is that [Display runnable query] in the profiler displays the correct statement (which i have tested, as mentioned).